# "Read book about my work" or "read books for my work"?

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition do I use when I want to say that I read books that help me to get better in my job: *about* or *for*? For example:

> I like reading books **for** my work.
>
> I like reading books **about** my work.

Can both prepositions be used? If so, then would they mean different things?
By the way, do I say *books for/about my work* or *book for/about my job*?

Comment: To me, _books about my work_ suggests that you are a writer, scientist etc. whose work is known to the public and has been written about. You could say something like _about the kind of work I do_. _For my work_ does have the implication _to help me with my work_.

Comment: I might say "I like reading books related to my work."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> reading books for my work.

This sounds like you are being forced to read books as a required part of your job, and the fact that you like it is incidental.

> I like reading books about my work.

This is what you want, here. You're really saying you like reading books *outside of work* that help you learn more about your profession, industry, etc.

Answer (score 0):

"I like reading books for my work." doesn't sound like the best usage to me - it implies that the person is an Editor, or proof-reader, or maybe a critic, and therefore reading forms a major part of their job description.

"I like reading books about my work." is also somewhat ambiguous (without any context) as it implies retrospection: "I like reading books about *my* work."

My suggestion would be: "I like reading books about my profession."